# MySQL find difference between two dates different columns

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
    select calldate as call_start, DATE_ADD(calldate, Interval duration SECOND) as call_end, duration
    from extensions 
    where ext = '2602' -- ext is the primary key
    AND DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = "2015-03-20"
    order by calldate asc
```

Returns the following:

[image: Mysql query]

How can i add a 4th column to get the difference between call_start from second row - call_end from first row? Something like this:

2015-03-20 10:21:20 - 2015-03-20 10:21:16 => 4 seconds, these 4 seconds should be added as a 4th field on the second row.

So it should look like for all calls :

```
call_start           call_end              duration       difference
2015-03-20 10:19:41  2015-03-20 10:21:16   95             null
2015-03-20 10:21:20  2015-03-20 10:21:29   9              4
```

Since the first row doesnt have an call_end from the call before, there should be a null.

**SOLUTION:**

```
 SET @prev_end=null;
 select calldate, date_add(calldate, interval duration SECOND) as end_date, duration,
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(timestampdiff(second,@prev_end,calldate)), '%i:%s')as difference,
  @prev_end:= date_add(calldate, interval duration SECOND) as test
  from extensions
  where ext = '2602'
  AND DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = "2015-03-20"
  order by calldate asc;
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: convert both dates in unix time stamp format and then you can find the difference.

Comment: @noddy the problem isnt the conversion, the problem is that i cant find the logic of the query

Comment: can you tell me what is the difference column meaning?

Comment: @noddy get the difference between call_start from second row - call_end from first row, and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following table

```
mysql> select * from extensions;
+---------------------+----------+
| calldate            | duration |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2015-03-20 10:19:41 |       95 |
| 2015-03-20 10:21:20 |        9 |
| 2015-03-20 10:21:35 |      277 |
| 2015-03-20 10:55:49 |       27 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

Now you can get the difference as

```
select
calldate as start_date,
end_date,
duration,
difference
from(
  select 
  calldate, 
  duration,
  date_add(calldate, interval duration SECOND) as end_date , 
  timestampdiff(second,@prev_end,calldate) as difference,
  @prev_end:= date_add(calldate, interval duration SECOND)
  from extensions,(select @prev_end:=null)x 
  order by calldate
)x

+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| start_date          | end_date            | duration | difference |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| 2015-03-20 10:19:41 | 2015-03-20 10:21:16 |       95 |       NULL |
| 2015-03-20 10:21:20 | 2015-03-20 10:21:29 |        9 |          4 |
| 2015-03-20 10:21:35 | 2015-03-20 10:26:12 |      277 |          6 |
| 2015-03-20 10:55:49 | 2015-03-20 10:56:16 |       27 |       1777 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+
```

In the above query all you need to add additional where clause inside the sub-query before the where clause as you have

```
where ext = '2602' -- ext is the primary key
AND DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = "2015-03-20"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL user defined variables for it.
Here is the query that will help you:

```
SET @end=null; -- reset the variable
SELECT 
      calldate as call_start,  
      DATE_ADD(calldate, Interval duration SECOND) as call_end, 
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, call_start, @end) as prev_diff, 
      @end:=DATE_ADD(calldate, Interval duration SECOND)
FROM extensions 
WHERE ext = '2602' -- ext is the primary key
AND DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = "2015-03-20"
ORDER BY calldate asc
```